# Hebrew RTL Print

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send to a printer hebrew text to print but it does not have a rtl parameter, so I manually need to reverse all text.
For example text like - "היי מה נשמע" will be printed like - "עמשנ המ ייה"

I have succeded to reverse only the Hebrew but when it's come together with signs and numbers it's not working well

```
static byte[] ReverseHebrewWords(string text)
{
    string[] lines = text.Split('\n');

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] words = Regex.Split(lines[i], @"\b");
        for (int j = 0; j < words.Length; j++)
        {
            // Check if the word contains Hebrew characters
            bool hasHebrewCharacters = words[j].Any(c => c >= '\u0590' && c <= '\u05FF');

            if (hasHebrewCharacters)
            {
                words[j] = ReverseHebrewWord(words[j]);
            }
        }

        Array.Reverse(words);
        lines[i] = string.Join("", words);
    }

    string reversedText = string.Join("\n", lines);

    return Encoding.GetEncoding(862).GetBytes(reversedText);

}

    static string ReverseHebrewWord(string word)
    {
        // Use LINQ to reverse the Hebrew word
        string reversedWord = new string(word.Where(c => char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.OtherLetter).Reverse().ToArray());
        return reversedWord + new string(word.Where(c => !char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide an *example* of a text which is printed in a wrong way (please, show the desired correct way as well)?

Answer (score 0):

Let's define the problem; as far as I can see, we want

- Reverse each **Hebrew** word (which is a non-empty sequence of **Hebrew** chars)
- Keep all the text intact as it is

If it is our task, I suggest

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string text = "היי מה נשמע";

string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"\p{IsHebrew}+", 
   match => string.Concat(match.Value.Reverse()));
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lZlXEy)